# Run app pool under domain user

Tags: iis-7, applicationpoolidentity

Seems easy enough... I go to my application pool advanced settings and set the service to run under an account that has access to the network files I need to read. I know I have entered the username and password correctly because it doesn't even let me submit with a bad username/password. I am using the domain\username format. I hook my site up to this app pool, run the site and I get a 503 error and the app pool immediately stops. I have googled this and every post I have seen (and there have been a lot of them) says that the password is wrong because it was changed in the domain but not updated. Yes, that can happen but I just entered the username and password and they were validated, I know that they are correct.

I am merely trying to read files that exist on a network drive and this seems like the best way to do it. If anyone else has any suggestions I am open to trying something else.

UPDATE: I get the following in my system event log (event id 5021):

The identity of application pool DocumentAPI is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error number.

I have also gone through the steps here which didn't help:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735179(v=ws.10).aspx

Thanks!

Comment: From the error message above "...or the user may not have batch logon rights".   Did you check the domain user has batch long rights?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to switch the 'Load User Profile' option to **false**. I have been battling the same issue as you for a couple days now. I found [this page](http://forums.iis.net/p/1176672/1975921.aspx) and was successfully at getting my site to load once again with the App Pool running.

*****edit*****

Further research and I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tijujohn/archive/2012/01/04/quot-503-service-unavailable-quot-and-quot-load-user-profile-quot.aspx) 
I deleted the profile for the App Pool that was giving me problems, set Load User Profiles back to **true**, restarted local IIS and everything still works.